# Combining cookies and sessions

Tags: php, cookies, session

This question Is  a result of various questions I had today about cookies.

As you know it's not save to handle the login process with cookies.

But how can I set a cookie when I am logged in and to be automatically loggedon  when I restart my browser?

If I redirect based on the existense of the cookie this is dangerous as someone else could just create a cookie. 
So what's the way to deal with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, an auto-login cookie does present a vulnerability, but you can mitigate some of these with various techniques, such as ensuring a cookie value can only be used once.

For more details, take a look at

- [Persistent Login Cookie Best Practice](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/)
- [Improved Persistent Login Cookie Best Practice](http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice)

And see these other fine StackOverflow answers

- [PART I: How To Log In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-website-authentication-beta/477578#477578)
- [PART II: How To Remain Logged In - The Infamous "Remember Me" Checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-website-authentication-beta/477579#477579)
- [PART III: Using Secret Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-website-authentication-beta/477580#477580)
- [PART IV: Forgotten Password Functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-website-authentication-beta/477583#477583)
- [PART V: Checking Password Strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-website-authentication-beta/477584#477584)
- [PART VI: Much More - Or: Preventing Rapid-Fire Login Attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-website-authentication-beta/477585#477585)
- [PART VII: Distributed Brute Force Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-website-authentication-beta/477586#477586)